# debugging PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am very new to PHP/MySQL and I don't know the best toolset or how to properly debug.

Here is the code snippet I'm working on. I have two main issues.

1: I'm noticing that escape sequences are not working. All of the \n are ignored in the page display.

2: My code is not entering the while loop, and therefore not displaying the result. When I run the same query on phpMyAdmin, I get one result.

This is the output:

> I'm in your db!echoinside postWe have a result table exists name:
>   outside post

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("****", "*****", "******", "******");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
echo "I'm in your db!";
echo "echo";
if( $_POST["submit"] ) {
echo "inside post"; 
    if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT Cust_name FROM SERVICE_TICKET WHERE Ticket_num=?"))) {
            echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
    }
    if (!$stmt->bind_param("i", $_POST['ticket'])) {
        echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }
    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }
    if (!$stmt->bind_result($Cust_name)) {
        echo "Binding output parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }
    else {
        echo "We have a result";
        echo "<table><br/>";
        echo "table exists";
        printf("<br/>\n\n\n\n\nname:  %s", $Cust_name);
        while ($stmt->fetch()){
            echo "in while loop";
            echo "<tr>\n<td>".$Cust_name."</td>\n</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }

}
echo "outside post";
?>
```

Adding html for the form:

```
<head>
    <title>Bicycle Store Service Ticket</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="web.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>ACME BICYCLE SHOP</h1>
    <h3 align="center">GET IN GEAR!</h3>

    <form action="search_service.php" method="post">
    <h3>CHECK A SERVICE TICKET</h3>

    <h4>Ticket Number: <input type="text" ticket="ticket">&nbsp;&nbsp;

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
    </form>

    <p><a href="index.html">HOME</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Any advice would be super helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem #1:** escape sequences *are* working but in HTML line breaks are "insignificant whitespace" and therefore are not displayed. You can add line breaks using the `<br>` tag.

**Problem #2:** it looks like your query returns an empty result set (there is no ticket with the number specified) and so the first invocation of `$stmt->fetch()` returns false.

**EDIT:** The line with the "ticket" input in your HTML should look like:

```
<h4>Ticket Number: </h4><input type="text" name="ticket">&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

So it's `name="ticket"` instead of `ticket="ticket"`, and the `<h4>` tag should be closed.

Comment: what does this mean? (there is no ticket with the number specified). How would I go about fixing that?

Comment: It means that I think (though I'm not sure) that no row in the database table `SERVICE_TICKET` has the value of `$_POST['ticket']` in its `Ticket_num` field, so your query (`SELECT Cust_name FROM SERVICE_TICKET WHERE Ticket_num=?`) returns no result. This is just an educated guess, but that is the first thing I would check.

Comment: Dang. So it's not a problem with the code but the query? I've double checked the query in myPHPadmin and it returns one result, but it doesn't work on the php side. Arrrrrgghhh.

Comment: The query seems fine to me, the value of the parameter is what I think causes the problem. Print the value of the `ticket` post parameter using `var_dump($_POST['ticket']);` and tell me if you see something strange.

Comment: That is helpful. It's returning NULL. I added the html form as well. Am I connecting them incorrectly?

Comment: Yes, the HTML is incorrect, I've edited my answer to include the solution.

Comment: BAM! There it is. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

> 1: I'm noticing that escape sequences are not working. All of the \n
>   are ignored in the page display.

`\n` is not escape chararcter. It is new line (LF ala line feed) character. And it is being ignored in HTML outside `<PRE>` block so either add `<PRE>` (but that would "kill" markup, or use `<br />` which means exaclty `\n` but "in HTML".

PS: do not use `?>` if you do not need.